# Issue with offset - Moment library using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using a `MomentJS` library and want to set the start from date in such format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`. This date I will send to some server which validates it.

**Code:**

`moment.utc(date).utcOffset(date.getTimezoneOffset()).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")`

The problem is that this code returns: `-0200` the timezone offset:

> "2023-12-30T22:00:00.000-0200"

This service accepts only such format "2023-12-30T22:00:00.000+0000" with +0000 offset.

When I set `utcOffset` as `0`: `moment.utc(date).utcOffset(0).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")`. It removes the offset but changes date to be invalid date:

`2023-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000`

Is there a way to set this date: `2023-12-30T22:00:00.000` and make offset always `+0000`? Thanks.

Comment: Why is 2023-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000 an invalid date?

Comment: @DaveNewton

This service reports an issue and validation fails. This date format must be as: "2023-12-30T22:00:00.000+0000". When I write this date in such format by myself to test it then it successfully validates. Any ideas how to make offset +0000?

Comment: Doesn't the date already have `+0000` when you do `moment.utc(date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")` ?

Comment: Also why did you tag this as `reactjs` when it is only about `momentjs` ?

Comment: @zoran404

Hello! My website is built on `ReactJS` and I think it's appropriate to specify such tag as well.

Comment: The `react` tag is not relevant if your question does not mention any react related stuff. You could use `momentjs` for formatting dates in any other framework or even in vanilla js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good. I have fixed this issue by setting the utcOffset as "+0000" - `utcOffset("+0000")`.

**Code:**

```
moment.utc(date).utcOffset("+0000").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
```

Now, this service validates this date and the request succeeds. This issue is resolved.

Comment: You didn't reply to my other comment: isn't that the default? Doesn't it already work if you remove `.utcOffset()` ?

Comment: @zoran404

If the `.utcOffset()` is removed then this date validation fails on the service.

Comment: That is odd, because when I try `moment.utc(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ') === moment.utc(date).utcOffset('+0000').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ')` it is `true`. Is it not equal when you run this?

Comment: @zoran404

Yes, it's odd but for some reason this service requires there to be added this offset: `utcOffset('+0000')`. The same strange reason why this service fails to validate such date: `2023-12-31T00:00:00.000+0000`.